# With PySpark dataframe locate value from one array based on index and copy to another array

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Within this dataframe I have the following two arrays: discount_applicaitons and line_items. The line_items array has an inner array called discount_allocaitons, which has a field named discount_application_index. The ask is to use the discount_application_index value and locate the corresponding "type" value in the discount_applications array index and copy it in the corresponding applications_type field.

Here is the dataframe:

```
records = '[{"_c":{"discount_applications":[{"type":"manual0"},{"type":"manual1"},{"type":"manual2"},{"type":"manual3"}],"line_items":[{"discount_allocations":[{"application_type":"","discount_application_index":0}]},{"discount_allocations":[{"application_type":"","discount_application_index":1}]},{"discount_allocations":[{"application_type":"","discount_application_index":2}]},{"discount_allocations":[{"application_type":"","discount_application_index":3}]}]}},{"_c":{"discount_applications":[{"type":"manual0"},{"type":"manual1"},{"type":"manual2"}],"line_items":[{"discount_allocations":[{"application_type":"","discount_application_index":0}]},{"discount_allocations":[{"application_type":"","discount_application_index":1}]},{"discount_allocations":[{"application_type":"","discount_application_index":2}]}]}},{"_c":{"discount_applications":[{"type":"manual0"},{"type":"manual1"},{"type":"manual2"}],"line_items":[{"discount_allocations":[{"application_type":"","discount_application_index":0}]},{"discount_allocations":[{"application_type":"","discount_application_index":1}]},{"discount_allocations":[{"application_type":"","discount_application_index":2}]}]}}]'
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([records]))
df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- _c: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- discount_applications: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- line_items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- discount_allocations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- application_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- discount_application_index: long (nullable = true)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|_c                                                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[manual0], [manual1], [manual2], [manual3]], [[[[, 0]]], [[[, 1]]], [[[, 2]]], [[[, 3]]]]]|
|[[[manual0], [manual1], [manual2]], [[[[, 0]]], [[[, 1]]], [[[, 2]]]]]                      |
|[[[manual0], [manual1], [manual2]], [[[[, 0]]], [[[, 1]]], [[[, 2]]]]]                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After the transformation, the ask is to have the dataframe look like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|_c                                                                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[manual0], [manual1], [manual2], [manual3]], [[[[manual0, 0]]], [[[manual1, 1]]], [[[manual2, 2]]], [[[manual3, 3]]]]]|
|[[[manual0], [manual1], [manual2]], [[[[manual0, 0]]], [[[manual1, 1]]], [[[manual2, 2]]]]]                             |
|[[[manual0], [manual1], [manual2]], [[[[manual0, 0]]], [[[manual1, 1]]], [[[manual2, 2]]]]]                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get your head clear and do the `transform` :)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    '_c', 
    F.expr("""
        struct(
            _c.discount_applications,
            transform(
                _c.line_items,
                x -> struct(
                    transform(
                        x.discount_allocations,
                        y -> struct(
                            _c.discount_applications[int(y.discount_application_index)].type as application_type,
                            y.discount_application_index as discount_application_index
                        )
                    ) as discount_allocations
                )
            ) as line_items
        )
    """)
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|_c                                                                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[manual0], [manual1], [manual2], [manual3]], [[[[manual0, 0]]], [[[manual1, 1]]], [[[manual2, 2]]], [[[manual3, 3]]]]]|
|[[[manual0], [manual1], [manual2]], [[[[manual0, 0]]], [[[manual1, 1]]], [[[manual2, 2]]]]]                             |
|[[[manual0], [manual1], [manual2]], [[[[manual0, 0]]], [[[manual1, 1]]], [[[manual2, 2]]]]]                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: this was awesome. The approach that I previously took had multiple dataframe struct and expr functions defined at the "_c" level(which has about 30 fields).  The approach you used moved the dataframe expr function at the top level and used struct functions within the expr. This allowed the transform function to reference higher-level fields and fields in a parallel level. Accessing fields at the same level is what I was struggling with. The approach you took is very elegant, clean, and impressive.